# Is there any way to specify SQL server version in mssql image?

Tags: sql-database, docker

*`scr.sitecore.com/sxp/sitecore-xp1-mssql:10.0.1-ltsc2019`* image is installing `SQL server -v 2014`. Is there any way to specify version 2016 or different image tag which will install 2016 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.
You can check the official list of all Sitecore images [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/docker-images/master/tags/sitecore-tags.md).

If you need another SQL server version image, you need to build that image by yourself.